# How to Underline text and color of uibutton in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, uibutton

I have one simple query, i need to underline UIButton text and color. I have under line text for uibutton, however regarding tint color its not working. I have set tint color from xib, its not taking from there.Below is my code.

```
 NSMutableAttributedString *commentString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Testing"];
[commentString addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:NSUnderlineStyleSingle] range:NSMakeRange(0, [commentString length])];
[_helpWithLoginLabel setAttributedTitle:commentString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a separate attribute for textColor (`NSForegroundColorAttributeName`). Here's an example:

```
NSArray * keys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:NSForegroundColorAttributeName, NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, nil];
NSArray * objects = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.descriptionTextView.textColor, [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleSingle], nil];
NSDictionary * linkAttributes = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
self.descriptionTextView.linkTextAttributes = linkAttributes;
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Grouping keys and objects in separate arrays to create a dictionary is not advisable coding style because editing the attributes later on is prone to errors. A cleaner way to do this is found in ChikabuZ's answer where he defines the key-value pair next to each other.

Answer (score 9):

In Swift:

```
let attributes = [NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle.rawValue]
let attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: button.currentTitle!, attributes: attributes)

button.titleLabel?.attributedText = attributedText
```

Answer (score 7):

Same response as @dequin using literals do get shorter syntax :

```
NSDictionary * linkAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:button.titleLabel.textColor, NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)};
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:button.titleLabel.text attributes:linkAttributes];            
[button.titleLabel setAttributedText:attributedString];
```

Comment: Crash with iOS7 (XCODE 8.1)

Answer (score 5):

Based on Alfie's answer I concocted this solution:

```
NSArray * objects = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.aButton.titleLabel.textColor, [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleSingle], nil];
NSArray * keys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:NSForegroundColorAttributeName, NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, nil];

NSDictionary * linkAttributes = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];

NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.aButton.titleLabel.text attributes:linkAttributes];

[self.aButton.titleLabel setAttributedText:attributedString];
```

Comment: I've posted an updated answer with literals to get a shorter syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
 extension UIButton {

    func UnderlineTextButton(title: String?, forState state: UIControlState)
    {
        self.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
        self.setAttributedTitle(self.attributedString(), for: .normal)
    }

    private func attributedString() -> NSAttributedString? {
        let attributes = [
            NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0),
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.black,
            NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue
            ] as [String : Any]
        let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: self.currentTitle!, attributes: attributes)
        return attributedString
    }
}
```

> Uses:-

```
button.UnderlineTextButton(title: "Click Here", forState:
UIControlState.normal)
```